# CSS -webkit-filter for other browsers (IE,Mozilla,Opera)

Tags: css, filter

I use `-webkit-filter: grayscale,sepia,saturate,brightness and etc.` but this effects support only Chrome and Safari browsers (http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/filters/)
How i can add this effects in others browsers? Maybe know any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

```
filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: sepia(0);
  filter: saturate(1);
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  filter: invert(0);
  filter: opacity(1);
  filter: brightness(1);
  filter: contrast(1);
  filter: blur(0px);

-ms-filter:
```

You can use these css for filter effect in IE and Chrome